# How do i make a program run with elevated privileges but not as root?

Tags: sudo, users, root, php, su

I am testing CTF like thing in my laptop and i have option to upload a PHP file which when executed grants shell to uploader, (reverse shell), however there is a problem. When i do

```bsh
su - www-data
cd /tmp
php -S 0.0.0.0:80 #upload.php is present uploaded data is saved in this dir
#it gives permission denied and i do
sudo php -S 0.0.0.0:80 #it runs
```

When i upload php shell myself, i get **root** shell. Hence, php server is being run as **root**. Rule is i cant user apache2 or nginx but php. Also, how can i run php server as elevated user (lets say www-data) and when i upload shell, i should get www-data like in common CTFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command to be able to run PHP under any port:

```
setcap -v cap_net_bind_service=+ep "$(readlink -f "$(which php)")"
```

If it returns: `/usr/bin/binary differs in [pe]` (it's an error) please run it without the `-v` argument first.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111970/discussion-on-answer-by-artem-s-tashkinov-how-do-i-make-a-program-run-with-elev).

Answer (score 2):

You are using a privileged port. Only `root` can listen to ports below 1024. This is the reason why e.g. apache starts as `root` (and remains), and the workers are started as `www-data` or whatever.

Try using a port above 1023.